# Properties of __proto__ in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below code

```
var person={
    firstname:"Geet",
    getFullName:function(){
        return this.firstname;
    }
}

var test={
    firstname:"Test"
}

test.__proto__=person;
for (var prop in test){
    console.log(prop + ': '+test[prop]);
}
```

Output:-

```
 firstname: Test
 getFullName: function (){
     return this.firstname;
 }
```

How the chain stops there. Why it does not print the properties of **proto** Object of person.How is this handled.

Comment: `for (var prop in test){` doesn't iterate over the prototype like that, in the first place.

Comment: The prototype of `person` is `Object.prototype`. That object doesn't have any *enumerable* properties. Simpler example: Iteration over `test = {}` doesn't log anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `__proto__` at all, see [MDN *`Object.prototype.__proto__`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

*for..in* only iterates over enumerable properties of the object and its `[[Prototype]]` chain. So you get *firstname* as it's directly on *test*. Then there is *getFullName* which is on *person*.

You don't get *person.firstname* is it's "shaddowed" by the *firstname* property on *test*. And that's it, there are no more enumerable properties on the remaining objects on the `[[Prototype]]` chain, being *Object.prototype* and *null*.

If you were expecting to see a `__proto__` property, you can't as it's not enumerable, see [*`ECMA-262 B.2.2.1 Object.prototype.__proto__`*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__).